# Ruby Cucumber on Jenkins (on Linux): Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter'

Tags: ruby, activerecord, jenkins, cucumber

I am working on setting up our test automation on Jenkins CI server which runs on Linux. (It works fine on Windows.) I am using oracle. I am getting this error.

```
   Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter'. 
   Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. 
   If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' 
   or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
   /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:7:
 in `rescue in <top (required)>'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.6.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced/oci_connection.rb:3:
  in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I checked the file below, it is there:

```
  -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 58018 Dec  2 22:23 oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb
```

I believe that I have everything I need.

```
  ruby 1.9.3 installed on /usr/local/bin
  required gems installed on /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.3/gems
     * activemodel (4.2.4)
     * activerecord (4.2.4)
     * activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.6.7)
     * activesupport (4.2.4)
     * ruby-oci8 (2.2.2)

  oracle instant client installed on /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1

    - instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0
    - instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0
    - instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.1.0.2.0

  Path is set: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
```

Gemfile:

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

   gem 'cucumber', '2.1.0'
   gem 'activerecord', '4.2.4'
   gem 'page-object', '1.2.0'
   gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '1.6.7'
   gem 'rspec'
   gem 'ruby-oci8', '2.2.2'
```

Database configuration: config/database.yml

```
DEV_DB:
      adapter: oracle_enhanced
      database: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxx.xxx.net)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx.xxx.net)))
```

Other environment:

```
   Cucumber 2.1.0
   Selenium Webdriver: 2.53.4
   Linux: x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What am I missing? Please share your thoughts.